# Can I ask a question about debugging problems in common DevOps tools?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

I'm running into a problem while running Docker for Windows, where it's unresponsive after restarting the MobyLinuxVM in Hyper-V. Would that be on topic *here*, or should I ask elsewhere?

An argument in favour of asking here would be that there are likely experts on Docker for Windows around, while an argument in favour of asking elsewhere would be that it's just not what this Stack was meant for. As noted in "[Defining site on-topic scope in help center?](http://meta.devops.stackexchange.com/q/11/187)", the scope isn't defined yet in the help.

---

*I went ahead and asked it:*

https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/507/187

*We'll see how it's received.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see why it will be off-topic on this site.

Docker is well on-topic here, and is also a major Devops-related technology out there.  (Psst, we already have [12 Docker-related posts](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/docker) and [9 container related ones](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/containers))

So, **this question is perfectly on-topic here.**  Also, welcome to the site :)

Comment: Thanks. I went ahead and asked it, then thought it to be a problem with Hyper-V rather then Docker. I'm still not sure if debugging problems in common DevOps tools should be on topic or not. But thanks for the welcome.

Comment: @SQB Yeah.  But, it's (the scope) best decided by the community.  We did that at DataScience, and community decided against such questions.  But here, it's too early to say. So, we need to wait until it is clear :)