# Custom close reasons:

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

After posting my thoughs on [Should debugging CI/CD problems caused by coding errors in the software product itself be on-topic?](https://devops.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143/should-debugging-ci-cd-problems-caused-by-coding-errors-in-the-software-product) it comes to my mind we need some usual 'off-topic' close reasons on top of the 2 actually present:

[image]

So add an answer with the close reason text as quote and the reasoning behind your proposition with how and when it should be used.
We, moderators, do keep the right to not include a reason whatever the votes are if we think it would be toxic for the site, in this case a meta post would be raised to explain the reasons.

Comment: You might also want to define the [help center](http://devops.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page linked in the first close reason (time for a different meta post, maybe?)

Comment: @Aurora0001 I've think of it, I do hope this post will lead to starting material for this page indeed :)

Answer (score 4):

Quoted from Stack Overflow reasons, trimmed for devops:

> This question was caused by a **problem that can no longer be reproduced**
>   or a **simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be
>   on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help
>   future readers.

This reason is quite self explanatory but I think it should be used when the solution was found in comments and doesn't deserve an answer which would solve someone else time later. For example: a simple typo error in a command or a quote missing, when resolved by 1 or 2 comments would fit.